# Variables available in all controllers?

Tags: zend-framework

Where and how to set variable value that is available in all controllers. I don't wont to use zend registry and don't want to extend Zend_Controller_Action. Is there is another way? I just want for example to set:

```
$a = "test";
```

and in Index controller to dump it:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction(){

            var_dump($a);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use the Zend_Registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global vars ruin the purpose of object oriented programming... use namespace or custom configs.

#### Solution 1

Use session Zend_Session_Namespace, here is [documentation on how to Zend_Session_Namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html).

1. Set set the value in namespace in bootstrap or something (wherever you see fit)
2. Retrieve the value from namespace in you controller/model/other

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, you can create some new class with static properties and use it's setters/getters to set and retrieve values.

E.g.

```
class SomeClass
{    
    static $hello = 'world';
}

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        var_dump(SomeClass::$hello);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add variables to the request object:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('a', 'hello');
```

Then retrieve it using:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('a);
```

But that is not the best way of doing it as you might accidentally overwrite a parameter a needed parameter.